# Javascript : Using .reduce and passing in a function to add strings

Tags: javascript, function, reduce

I'm trying to use the .reduce method passing in a function and an initial value 'Stack' but I've been getting undefined.

I added a console.log in the reduce method to see what may be going wrong, and it seems to be related to the accumulator, which keeps returning undefined, but I can't understand why.

Thank you for your assistance.

```
function addingSpace(string1, string2){
  let result = string1 + " " + string2;
  return result;
}

function combineStr(array, callback, iv){
  let result = array.reduce((acc, cv) => {
    callback(acc, cv)
  }, iv);
  return result;
}

let testArr = ['flow', 'is', 'amazing']
console.log(combineStr(testArr, addingSpace, 'Stack')) // 'Stack flow is amazing'
```

Comment: You need to return the value back to the accumulator in reduce, ie `return callback(acc, cv)`

Comment: oh my goodness, thank you so much Terry!

Answer (score 0):

To further expand on my comment, the callback function you’re using in `Array.prototype.reduce` isn’t returning anything, so it defaults to returning `undefined`.

You will need to return the value so that the accumulator is updated for the next iteration:

```
return callback(acc, cv);
```